# PHP and XPath queries

Tags: php, xpath

I need to strip some values and also some raw HTML from an HTML document. I thought of using XPath, but I cannot get my queries to work.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<div class="unit-id">
   <div class="title">
      some title-1
   </div>

   <div class="another-class">
      another class
   </div>
   <p>segwegw1<p>
   <p>segwegw1<p>
   <p>segwegw1<p>
   <p>segwegw1<p>
   <ul>
     <li>jfjfj</li>
     <li>jfjfj</li>
     <li>jfjfj</li>
   </ul>
</div>


<div class="unit-id">
   <div class="title">
      some title-2
   </div>
   <div class="another-class">
      some other class
   </div>
   <p>segwegw2<p>
   <p>segwegw2<p>
   <p>segwegw2<p>
   <p>segwegw2<p>
</div>


<div class="unit-id">
   <div class="title">
      some title-3
   </div>
   <div class="some-other-class">
      some other data
   </div>
   <p>segwegw3<p>
   <p>segwegw3<p>
   <p>segwegw3<p>
   <p>segwegw3<p>
</div>
```

So I'd like the query to iterate through each `div` with a unit-id class and return the value of the `divs` with a class of `title` and the rest of the HTML, excluding any more `divs` so just the `p` tags and `ul` stuff for that particular unit-id classed `div`, and then the next iteration.

Is that possible? Could you provide me with an example of how to write this query? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What have you attempted so far, stackoverflow is not about writing your code but more fixing the problem you have, you have no code to show.

Comment: I have created the query to return a collection of elements that are divs with the class unit-id (query("//div[@class='unit-id']"), however I then need to return all the following non div elements until the next div with a class of 'unit-id'. This I'm struggling with. Is there a better method than using an xpath query?

Comment: @Jessica - Some of the best questions ever asked in StackOverflow were asked without showing any unsuccessful code. Check out this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Comment: If you want XPath answers, you should at least fix your HTML to be somewhat valid XML (eg., closing the `<p/>` tags instead of repeating the opening one). Also, please provide the expected result, your question is somewhat unclear and answering it would include lots of guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does something like what you're looking for:

```
function get_content($data){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    //load HTML string into document object
    if ( ! @$doc->loadHTML($data)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    //create XPath object using the document object as the parameter
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = "//div[@class='unit-id']";
    //XPath queries return a NodeList
    $res = $xpath->query($query);
    $out = array();
    foreach ($res as $key => $node){
        //subquery
        $sub = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="title"]', $node);
        $out[$key]['title'] = trim($sub->item(0)->nodeValue);
        foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('p') as $key2 => $value){
            $out[$key]['par'][$key2] = $value->nodeValue;
        }
        foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('li') as $key2 => $value){
            $out[$key]['list'][$key2] = $value->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Please note that you have errors in your HTML. You're closing paragraph tags should have the trailing slash `</p>`.

Here's the output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'title' => string 'some title-1' (length=12)
      'par' => 
        array
          0 => string 'segwegw1' (length=8)
          1 => string 'segwegw1' (length=8)
          2 => string 'segwegw1' (length=8)
          3 => string 'segwegw1' (length=8)
      'list' => 
        array
          0 => string 'jfjfj' (length=5)
          1 => string 'jfjfj' (length=5)
          2 => string 'jfjfj' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array
      'title' => string 'some title-2' (length=12)
      'par' => 
        array
          0 => string 'segwegw2' (length=8)
          1 => string 'segwegw2' (length=8)
          2 => string 'segwegw2' (length=8)
          3 => string 'segwegw2' (length=8)
```

Comment: Great. That really helps me out. It was doing a sub query on the initial query that was confusing me. Cheers!